# Как использовать метод из .so библиотеки в своем проекте?

Tags: java, jni

У меня есть файл .so, это как я понял нативная библиотека, но уже в скомпилированном виде. Мне нужно использовать метод из этой библиотеки в своем Java проекте. Можно ли это сделать? Если можно, то как? Каким сборщиком мне собирать свой проект чтобы это провернуть(Maven, Gradle)?

Comment: Любым сборщиком. Вряд ли у вас это получится, но можете попробовать. Вы же в теге указали JNI, вот по всем заветам и делайте. В интернете полно статей. Здесь же лучше задавать конкретные вопросы, прикладывая код.

Answer (score 0):

По опыту решения аналогичных задач рекомендую использовать Java Native Access (JNA).

Упрощенно говоря, описывается Java-интерфейс/класс, соответствующий нативной библиотеке. При помощи JNA загружается эта библиотека, а дальнейшая работа в Java-коде производится через интерфейс/класс.

Это не так просто, поскольку нужно понимать соответствие описываемого Java-интерфейса/класса API нативной библиотеки, но это проще, чем возиться с JNI. Часто можно обойтись только Java-кодом.